Enable headers with underscore
We have deployed a spring boot application onto Rancher Kubernetes. We have an header DO_YOU_KNOW_ME that is passed in most of the requests. Looks like this is being skipped. We have tried without underscores do-you-know-me and surprisingly we are able to see this in the headers.
Is there any ingress annotation that can be used to allow headers with underscore ?
